# Anybody knows how to send a audio/image using NodeJs to a Telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, post, upload, axios, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send an audio file to a Telegram bot using **node** and **Telegram Api** (sendAudio in this case)

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

let payload = new FormData();
payload.append('chat_id', 'ID');
payload.append('audio', './audio.mp3');
// OR  payload.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(`./audio.jpg`));

axios.post(
    'https://api.telegram.org/botMyToken/sendAudio',
    payload,
    {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;`
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

console result is a big obj with:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (/Users/username/TelegramBot/MyBot/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/Users/username/TelegramBot/MyBot/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/username/TelegramBot/MyBot/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19) 

headers:
  { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
    accept: 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0' },
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.telegram.org/botMyToken/sendAudio',
  data:
   FormData {
    _overheadLength: 210,
    _valueLength: 89,
    _valuesToMeasure: [],
    writable: false,
    readable: true,
    dataSize: 0,
    maxDataSize: 2097152,
    pauseStreams: true,
    _released: true,
    _streams: [],
    _currentStream: null,
    _boundary: '--------------------------432591578870565694802709',
    _events: {},
    _eventsCount: 0 } },
```

what am I doing wrong?
I tried send same file using a simple form, and PHP and it worked, I don't get what's wrong in this code.

Comment: what does the `console.log(error)` outputs?

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending an audio file, but a string containing a **local** path to a file, which Telegram of course doesn't have access.

> Audio file to send. Pass a file_id as String to send an audio file
>   that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as
>   a String for Telegram to get an audio file from the Internet, or
>   upload a new one using multipart/form-data.

The telegram documentation is clear, `audio` must be:

- file_id
- url
- Post the file using multipart/form-data

You can try this:

```
payload.append('audio', fs.createReadStream('./audio.mp3'));
```

I recommend using [telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=working-with-files) which will do all the heavy lifting, and will allow you to use a **local** file path.

```
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

bot.on('message', (ctx) => {

  // send file
  ctx.replyWithAudio({ source: './audio.mp3' })

});

bot.startPolling();
```

Comment: Don't, just as I told you, send a valid data for `audio`, and not a local path, which is your exact problem, as my answer describes.

Comment: can you tell me how to send the file audio, it's what I'm trying to get

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I never used `form-data` package before, but according to their documentation that's the way to send a file. But telegram may require a different format.

Comment: Without axios it's easy, it's a problem on how you're doing the request, never used axios myself, but I do recommend using telegraf, or you'll have a bad time coding everything yourself. I will test with axios when I get home in a few hours.

Comment: I tried using **request** module, and it worked... I'm doing something wrong with **axios** though

Comment: That's what I said, axios is not as good as the `request` module imo.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use getHeaders() function of FormData module. This solved my problem with sending photo to telegram bot

```
payload.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(`./audio.jpg`));
... 
headers: payload.getHeaders()
...
```